# 'on your own' versus 'by yoursself'

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> A: You can do that on your own.
>
> B: You can do that by yourself.

There were several occassions, when I was wondering what's more appropriate, like:

> I can write this on my own / by myself.
>
> I can fix that on my own / by mysel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two expressions are very, very similar even though there is a slight difference with no loss of meaning in certain contexts, it Depends;

- by yourself Suggests nobody else, just that person.
- on your own Suggests without any help.
  **For example:**
- *He went to the cinema by himself.* (He had nobody with him)
- *He thought of the idea on his own.* (Nobody gave him the idea)